# How to loop Python code, changing details each time?

Tags: python, loops

This code does what it is supposed to do, but I do not know how to loop it correctly. Code itself is working perfectly, but it is way too long, so I need to put it in a loop. My code looks as follows:

```
    random1 = random.randint(0, 100)
    random2 = random.randint(0, 100)
    solution1 = random1 + random2
    print ("What is ", random1, " + ", random2, "?")
    user_answer1 = input()
    if solution1 == int(user_answer1):
         print ("Answer is correct!")
         score += 1
    else:
         print ("Answer is wrong!")

    print ("Your score is ", score, "! Let's continue.")
```

This is only a 1/10 of the code, this is repeated 9 more times.

Okay, I know a bit about how to use loops. The problem in this code is that I need the program to have 3 addition , 4 subtraction and 3 multiplication questions. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You have a lot of redundant parantheses. I will remove them to improve readability. I will keep them around the `print` argument in case you are using Python 3, but in 2.X even there they are not needed.

Answer (score 4):

Just put your code in a method and loop over it 10 times:

```
import random

def ask_questions():
    random1 = random.randint(0, 100)
    ...

for i in range(10):
    ask_questions()
```

Comment: Can you edit so this is part of code, because changing code is going to take hours.

Comment: I'll try to do it this way

Answer (score 4):

Make it a function where you can specify if you want to add, subtract or multiply:

```
def question(op):
    random1 = (random.randint(0, 100))
    random2 = (random.randint(0, 100))
    if op == '+':
        solution1 = random1+random2
    elif op == '-':
        solution1 = random1-random2
    else:
        solution1 = random1*random2
    print ("What is ",random1, op,random2, "? ")
    user_answer1 = (input())
    if solution1 == int(user_answer1):
        print ("Answer is correct!")
        return 1
    else:
        print ("Answer is wrong!")
        return 0

score = 0
for i in range(3):
    score += question('+')
for i in range(4):
    score += question('-')
for i in range(3):
    score += question('*')

print ("Your score is",score,"!")
```

Comment: I would go further, and use: `for op in '+' * 3 + '-' * 4 + '*' * 3: score += question(op)`

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, using [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html), [eval](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=eval#eval) and other Python niceties:

```
from random import randint
from itertools import chain, repeat

def question(op, a=0, b=100):
  operation = "{} {} {}".format(randint(a, b), op, randint(a, b))
  correct = eval(operation) == int(input("\nWhat is {}?\n> ".format(operation)))
  print("Your answer is {}!".format("correct" if correct else "wrong"))
  if not correct: print("It's {}.".format(eval(operation)))
  return correct

score = sum(map(question, chain.from_iterable(map(repeat, '+-*', [3, 4, 3]))))

print("\nYour total score is {}!".format(score))
```